# How to I give my google chrome extension permission to work on all sites?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm trying to make a google chrome extension that I want to work on all sites, but I can't figure out how to configure the permissions to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a helpful page in the docs called ["Match Patterns"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

You need `"<all_urls>"` (literally as written) to request access to every site. It is actually required for some APIs like tab capture.